# how to play video more than one time in customized web view in android?

Tags: android, html5-video

I am developing an android app in which i have to load a web page and then play a movie clip from it in a customized web view. I have done almost every thing there and even movie is played in web view. But problem is that when we play it once it does not play again. Even when same link is accessed via android standard browser it works fine. But in customized web view video only played once. Any body please tell me that why is that happening and also how to over come this issue as my app is just in finish line.
Thanks:

Comment: try  using frame layout and adding the webview to it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8011027/1220586

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

}
```

In your WebChromeClient.