# WebView memory leak in android app

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I'm using a layout with a webview ... every time I load a page in the web view I notice in the task manager that I get a memory leak... seems like my webview keeps in memory all pages' data... how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Are you setting a WebViewClient to your WebView before you load the URL?

Comment: Whatever "task manager" is, it is not a reliable indicator of memory leaks. If you want to determine if you have memory leaks, dump the heap from DDMS (or use the `Debug` class) and analyze the heap with MAT.

Comment: @serkan yes I do, what should change?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes it's true, anyway my application is getting slow.. looking for this issue, I found that is a known bug since 2009 and I don't know if has been fixed ... I'm using Cyanogen mod, maybe here still exists..

Comment: Look at [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5067). Although, as [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said, using the task manager is not a very effective way of identifying memory leaks. Also, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130654/memory-leak-in-webview).