# More than 3 fingers on webview causes app crash?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview

Like the title says, when I drag more than 2 fingers across my webview. It causes my app to crash with the following log:

```
05-18 23:30:53.435: ERROR/dalvikvm(8204): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
05-18 23:30:53.435: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): JNI local reference table (0x51d30d68) dump:
05-18 23:30:53.435: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): Last 10 entries (of 512):
05-18 23:30:53.435: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 511: 0x4114bfb8 java.lang.Class<android.view.VelocityTracker>
05-18 23:30:53.435: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 510: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.435: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 509: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 508: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 507: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 506: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 505: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 504: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 503: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 502: 0x4188c960 android.view.MotionEvent
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): Summary:
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 4 of java.lang.Class (4 unique instances)
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 2 of java.lang.String (2 unique instances)
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 1 of java.lang.String[] (2 elements)
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 1 of android.os.MessageQueue
05-18 23:30:53.445: WARN/dalvikvm(8204): 504 of android.view.MotionEvent (1 unique instances)
05-18 23:30:53.445: ERROR/dalvikvm(8204): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
05-18 23:30:53.445: ASSERT/libc(8204): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 8204 (MangaGalaxyFree)
```

Stacktrace from my Desire HD running 4.2.2

I have looked up the error and it looks like the issue of Webview memory leak but I'm not sure. Webview is displaying dynamically generated HTML with some assets in the assets folder such as image/javascript. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Start checking these:

   - [WebView memory leak in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605177/webview-memory-leak-in-android-app)
   - [Android WebView Memory Leak when using Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278149/android-webview-memory-leak-when-using-assets)
   - [Viewpager Webview memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942929/viewpager-webview-memory-issue)
2. Try the Memory Analyzer Tool plugin instructions given at the following link to examine the details:

   - http://therockncoder.blogspot.ca/2012/09/fixing-android-memory-leak.html
3. Try posting some code so we can try to help you.