# Android WebView lifecycle

Tags: android, webview, lifecycle

I'm currently somewhat confused as to how (or if?) I'm supposed to manage the lifecycle of the WebViews in my Android application. The app seems to have a much bigger impact on the devices battery than I think it should have and I suspect the cause might be mismanagement of the WebViews on my part. The answers I found only ever seem to raise part of the problem and I couldn't find some kind of tutorial or more general answer on this so far.

When I started developing my application, I thought that WebViews were supposed to follow the lifecycle of their respective Activity, then I stumbled across the methods onPause, onResume, pauseTimers, resumeTimers, saveState and restoreState.

But I don't really unterstand what implications each one of these have for the lifecycle of their WebView and what it means for battery/memory/CPU management to use or not use any of these. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823497/8074879) mentioned it'd be "cheaper to destroy the webviews and recreate them again", but didn't go into further detail and the posted link is dead.

Could anyone please give a brief explanation and introduction on what is best practice for managing a WebViews lifecycle?