# Android WebView Memory Leak when using Assets

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I've recently noticed that when I load a webview based off code from a file (using assets or a local directory), the WebView will leak the memory once the destroy() method is called.  I've narrowed it down to a referencing issue. The program/webview makes copies of the original view and loses the references in the JNI table - this eventually causes the program to crash after 512 entries.

I have seen this article, but the non-leaking webview fix does not seem to work with HTML in the assets or external folders.

[Memory leak in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130654/memory-leak-in-webview)

The issue does not exist when the application is entirely server based; but, I need the application to be able to "sync" data and update the offline repo with these views.

Further info:  I have taken the webviews and put them in a ViewPager to allow for scrolling.   This issue did not exist in 3.2.4/1 but has appeared in 4.0.3. I get a lot of JNI Warnings, (failed to find entry) and they still exist after the views are destroyed.  I've looked at it through the hprof, and I have noticed that the HTML is staying residual in lost variables.

Any light on how to correct this behavior would be appreciated.

Edit:

Specifics on the crash

```
Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
"Thread-375" prio=5 tid=15 RUNNABLE
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41504a90 self=0x1a9cf80
| sysTid=10314 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27159240
| schedstat=( 455083000 66745000 774 ) utm=30 stm=15 core=3

at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:35)
at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:573)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

UPDATE:

To fix this issue, you have to load from the SD Card, or some other storage mechanism. The bug is permanent when a Javascript file is loaded, I don't know if it's fixed in Chrome, but it does not seem to be fixed in Browser in the newest OS.

Comment: try to load files from SD card code: webtemp.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/assetssd/example.html);

Comment: Are you serious...?  I was the person who emailed this answer >.>

Comment: Joke of the day!! thanks for I identifying!! :) !My friend Yes you are Right!:) sorry for that!I doesn't seen the asked name while commenting!!  finally the ans is out!! but the above "local ref table" error solved but "E/dalvikvm-heap(16169): Out of memory on a 2310160-byte allocation." error comes!!!

Comment: Lol! It's okay :P  I should have posted this on many other forums and bug reports. oh well.

Answer (score 2):

.destroy() --> Destroys the internal state of this WebView. This method should be called after this WebView has been removed from the view system.