# Webview keeps leaking memory in android

Tags: java, android

I am using in my app the webview widget to show the Google maps with some kml overlay on it. 
But when I call the loadurl() function memory increases every time.

I have put this code:

```
     if(webView!=null){
        webView.destroyDrawingCache();
        webView.stopLoading();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.freeMemory();
        webView.destroy();
        webView = null;
        System.gc();    
    }
```

To create a new webview every time I need it, but nothing I've read and other responses but no one gives an answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278149/android-webview-memory-leak-when-using-assets