# Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached

Tags: android

I am getting this error when the device changes orientation:

`Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached`

With this code:

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (adView != null)
    {
        adView.destroy();
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this? How do I avoid this error?

Comment: maybe the whole call stack will help

Comment: Before calling destroy you need to remove the WebView from the views system
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#destroy()
Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You first need to detach the Webview:

```
webViewPlaceholder.removeView(myWebView);
myWebView.removeAllViews();
myWebView.destroy();
```

That did it for me.

Comment: Thanks. This error suddenly started to appear, no issues prior. This fixed it again.

Comment: Wandering why this answer marked as correct answer. It has no relation to initial question. Real correct answer is from Matthew

Comment: The `myParentView.removeView(myWebView);` is what does the trick, actually.

Comment: Wow. It seems like this actually fixed [a long-standing memory leak in my app](https://github.com/vickychijwani/quill/issues/75). Thank you!

Comment: @Ernest, `AdView` is just a specialized `WebView`, which is why this answer is marked correct.  Replace `myWebView` in the example with the name of the `AdView`.

Comment: @user1668939 what is this declared `webViewPlaceholder`

Comment: Where do I need to add this code? Can you provide a full example widget?

Answer (score 31):

To avoid the error you just need to remove all views before you destroy the ad.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    if (adView != null)
    {
        adView.removeAllViews();
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna disappoint you, but this doesn't work. I have the same problem with my WebView and I always close my WebView like this and the error exists nevertheless.

Comment: This works for me. The official admob doc should add adView.removeAllViews();
I don't want the ad still consumes resources after the activity is destroyed.

Comment: It don't solve the problem completely. I also meet it, app still crash although use this code

Answer (score 10):

```
 @Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if (mWebView != null) {
        mWebView.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to my tests, this issue is revealed in AdMob SDK v6.4.1 and at least on Android v4.2.2+. When testing the AdMob sample application referred to at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android (direct link is http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/Android_XML.zip), the issue occurs when closing the sample screen.

My work-around is rather:

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null)
    {
      final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
      if (viewGroup != null)
      {
        viewGroup.removeView(adView);
      }
      adView.destroy();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Hope that helps other people, and that the AdMob will very soon fix that annoying issue.

Comment: who knew ! done with the nasty leak. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Great answer! Works even now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

For you don't get this error you need to have a parent layout, e.g. : RelativeLayout and remove the WebView component, that might had been defined on you layoutWebView.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webviewRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerAlarmsWebViewTxt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then you assign it to an instance variable e.g. :

```
_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webviewRelativeLayout);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

and on Destroy do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    _layout.removeView(webView);
    webView.setFocusable(true);
    webView.removeAllViews();
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Almost 10 years later this answer still helping people (me)!