# Music on website won't stop with back button

Tags: android, android-webview, back, keydown

I'm working on an app with a WebView but the website has music in the background. I have code when the back button is pressed will go back to previous page until it can go back anymore and will go back to main menu. Problem is that when it goes back to main menu, the music does not stop and I need it to stop. Sorry only a beginner. Any help would be awesome!

Code:

```
       @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    myWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    this.finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Xml

```
 <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: That's odd. Try removing the webview from its container first and then calling destroy() on it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12408703/833647

Comment: Could you show me with my example. Sorry only a beginner

Comment: Please edit your post and add your layout.xml, I need to access the parent view of the webview.

Comment: Done, sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your XML to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView 
       android:id="@+id/webView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Get your LinearLayout in your activity (just in the same place you got your WebView):

```
LinearLayout root;
```

(then in onCreate())

```
root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
```

Then

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            }
            else {
                root.removeView(myWebView); // <- 
                myWebView.removeAllViews(); // <- add these lines
                myWebView.destroy();        // <-
                this.finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try >> in manifest.xml put this `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for the webview activity