# OnDestroy() called multiple times

Tags: android

I have noticed that the onDestroy() method of a fragment gets called multiple times - why would this be? I would expect only 1 call.

Comment: its called only once, please check lifecycle, there has to be something specific with your code post it here so that we can have a look.

Comment: @Techfist No it is not

Comment: `Fragment.onDestroy()` is called only once per instance. After that, the instance should be available for the garbage collector to reclaim. It is dead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's normal for an `Activity` or `Fragment` to get `onDestroy()`-ed multiple times. For example, when you change the device orientation, the current `Activity` goes through `onDestroy()` and then a new instance of the same `Activity` goes through `onCreate()`, now in the new orientation.

You might be confusing this for `finish()`, which gets called when the `Activity` gets "killed" per se and happens only once when you navigate away from it.

Comment: This is nonsense. A **given `Activity` instance** will have `onDestroy()` called only once (or not at all). It will **never** be called more than once! If you change your device orientation, Android destroys the current active instance of the `Activity` (and calls `onDestroy()`) and then it creates **a new instance** of the `Activity`. This answer is unfortunately wrong and misleading.

Comment: In any case, the OP asked about `onDestroy()` of `Fragment`, not `Activity.

Comment: You're absolutely right, edited. Either way, the answer has been accepted, so I guess the question was asked due to the OP thinking that `onDestroy()` gets called only a single time, which is false for both `Activity` and `Fragment`

Comment: Also reworded the answer - 'instance' sounds like I'm talking about a Java Object instance, where I actually mean 'an Activity', which can go through many `Activity` object instances during its lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. However, your answer is still wrong/misleading/confusing. You write that `onDestroy()` can be called multiple times. This is wrong. That's like saying `onCreate()` can be called multiple times. Also wrong. Not only that, but in the second part of your answer you write that `finish()` is only called once. If you mean "per class and not per instance then this is also wrong (and conflicts with the statement about `onDestroy()`. Saying that `onDestroy()` can be called multiple times, even as you have written it, is misleading. Using the same logic you can say that ...

Comment: ...all methods can be called multiple times, since I can start the app and then stop it and then start it again and then all methods could be called multiple times. This is just wrong. Sorry. `onDestroy()` is called at most once. Period. Anything else is just confusing.

Comment: Once per `Activity` object. Multiple times per screen lifecycle, if you go through configuration changes and let the OS handle those for you. Either way, your input is valuable, but I'm afraid changing the answer more than I have already will turn this answer into a mess.

Comment: You could just delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`onDestroy()` = The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.

This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called `finish()` on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space.

You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()` method.

Comment: OP asked about `onDestroy()` of `Fragment`, not `Activity`.