# how to remove webview android programmatically

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-view

I am trying to remove webview and recreate webview to load a new html file but i am getting blank page while loading the html url

actually i am initially loading webview on Oncreate() and then i will loading a webpages from different activity that why i am using onActivityResult() to load a new webpage in same webview . The problem is i am getting blank page by using above code but i need to load webpage properly and how?

Comment: add complete code

Comment: try out this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418503/destroy-webview-in-android

Comment: you dont need to destory the webview or reinitialize.. just load another URL `webview.loadUrl(url);`..

Comment: u can see my code i have reinitialize the webview but i am getting blank page