# Kotlin 1.5.0 NPE when properly destroying a WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-1.5

My app destroys webviews as per the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418503/destroy-webview-in-android)).

```
 parentConstraintLayout.removeView(webView)
 webView.apply{
     clearHistory()
     clearCache(true)
     loadUrl("about:blank")
     onPause()
     removeAllViews()
 }
```

This has been working fine up until upgrading the Kotlin version from 1.4.32 to 1.5.0
With Kotlin 1.5.0, the webView variable becomes null after      `parentConstraintLayout.removeView(webView)` is executed. `clearHistory()` throws an NPE and the app crashes. `webView` and `parentConstraintLayout` are both declared in the XML.

I've verified that everything else being equal, the issue occurs with Kotlin 1.5.0 / 1.5.20 but not with 1.4.32. Why does this happen with upgrading Kotlin, and what can I do to fix it?

Here is `webView`

```
<WebView
     android:id="@+id/webView"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/webViewToolbarContainer"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```

and `parentConstraintLayout` - it's direct parent

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentConstraintLayout"
>
```

Here is the crash log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.clearHistory()' on a null object reference
       at com.myapp.android.screens.sweepstakes.ui.DetailActivity.destroyWebView(DetailActivity.java:25)
       at com.myapp.android.screens.ui.DetailActivity.close(DetailActivity.java:21)
       at com.myapp.android.screens.impl.DetailParentPresenter.onTerminationDialogOptionSubmitClicked(DetailParentPresenter.java:69)
       at com.myapp.android.screens.ui.DetailActivity$showSubsequentTerminationDialog$1.invoke(DetailActivity.java:26)
       at com.myapp.android.screens.ui.DetailActivity$showSubsequentTerminationDialog$1.invoke(DetailActivity.java:2)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.callbacks.DialogCallbackExtKt.invokeAll(DialogCallbackExtKt.java:26)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.onActionButtonClicked$core(MaterialDialog.java:34)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.internal.button.DialogActionButtonLayout$onFinishInflate$1.onClick(DialogActionButtonLayout.java:8)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
       at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Please provide your crash log for more detail

Comment: Added it on at the end

Comment: @user1114 did you find the cause of this? I am facing a similar issue where removeView call is making the Kotlin Synthetics variable to become null. It was not happening pre Kotlin 1.5 but I can't see to find any related cause in change logs.

Answer (score 0):

you can override loadWebView. Before you load web view you can clear the data and cookies

```
    override fun loadWebView(userAccessToken: Token) {
    mWebView.clearCache(true)
    mWebView.clearFormData()
    mWebView.clearHistory()
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
    CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
    mWebView.webViewClient = object : BaseWebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
           // TODO url validator return true/false

        }
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin synthetics on 1.5.0 calls findViewById() for every time you reference it, instead of using a cached one on 1.4.x. Since you removed it from the view, findViewById() returns null.

You can use this instead:

```
 webView.apply{
     parentConstraintLayout.removeView(this)
     clearHistory()
     clearCache(true)
     loadUrl("about:blank")
     onPause()
     removeAllViews()
 }
```