# WebView leaking memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview

We have on a device a WebView which loads 10 pages with some javascript included.
The problem is that is leaking and I don't know where could it be from.
Basically there is an Activity which has ViewPager, and that ViewPager has .setAdapter on 
"new WebPagerAdapter()". WebPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter.

The problem is that this is leaking somewhere and everything we tried is not working. It looks like on a device it jumps around 5-10mb constantly RAM usage but it is increasing just a little all the time, and after like a day it is on 150MB used. 
Heap dumps don't show anything useful and "dumpsys meminfo" shows more and more "Views" under Objects?
I don't know what to try anymore, any suggestions?

This is instatiateItem on WebPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    NonLeakingWebView mwebView = new NonLeakingWebView(activity.getApplicationContext());
    if (mWebViewClientLogScreen == null)
        mWebViewClientLogScreen = new WebViewClientLogScreen(activity);
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClientLogScreen);
    mwebView.clearCache(true);
    mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    if (pos >= lenght)
        pos = 0;


    mwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setTag(String.valueOf(pos));
    mwebView.loadUrl(imageArray[pos]);
    ++pos;
    // view.addView(mwebView);
    container.addView(mwebView, 0);

    return mwebView;
}
```

NonLeakingWebView is a WebView from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949378/1088975

Destroy item

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    try {
        NonLeakingWebView mWebView = (NonLeakingWebView) object;
        container.removeView(mWebView);
        mWebView.removeAllViews();
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        mWebView.clearView();
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.freeMemory();
        mWebView.destroy();
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(mWebView, (Object[]) null);
        mWebView = null;
        System.gc();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

There is .onPause() because we tried to pause to see if there is any difference

```
public class NLAwebPager extends ViewPager {

public NLAwebPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NLAwebPager(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    return true;
}
```

}

This is custom ViewPager which on main activity does this

```
    NLPager= (NLAwebPager) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    NLPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            WebView mWebVIew = (WebView) NLPager.findViewWithTag(--arg0);
            if (mWebVIew != null)
                mWebVIew.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // Log.e("ss", "s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
```

And this is a Runnable which on every X seconds changes adapter page

```
private Runnable runnable_webPage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i = txtTime.getCurrentItem();
        txtTime.setCurrentItem(++i, false);

        mHandlerWebPage.removeCallbacks(runnable_webPage);
        mHandlerWebPage.postDelayed(runnable_webPage, webPageChangeTimer);
    }

};
```

And a custom WebViewClient for progress bar

```
public class WebViewClientLogScreen extends WebViewClient {

LogScreen wpa;

public WebViewClientLogScreen(FragmentActivity wpa) {
    this.wpa = (LogScreen) wpa;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    try {
        ProgressBar mbar = (ProgressBar) view.getTag();
        mbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    try {
        ProgressBar mbar = (ProgressBar) view.getTag();
        mbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    try {
        wpa.doShowMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using traceview? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Nothing helpful there, I think

Comment: You should be able to trace memory leak following this article http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html It's not an easy task, but if you really have memory leaks using heap dumps and MAT will find it. You just need deeper understanding of this tools.