# Android Webview Memory management

Tags: android, memory-management, webview

I am adding dynamically a list of items to a html which loads in webview. Its loading successfully.

My question is the memory taken by webview should depends on heap memory of our application?

Is there any way to monitor the memory occupied by my webview?

I heard that the webview memory is dependent on the chromium means at the system level is that right?

Comment: look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130654/memory-leak-in-webview

Comment: No not this, If the html is having huge data like images with very big resolutions. Is that size will effect on application heap?